# How to properly initialize git-svn clone of a repository with nonstandard layout?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to work using git with svn repository that has the following rough layout:

> RepositoryHone
>
> - -> Documents
> - -> ExtraDocuments
> - -> playground
> - -> playground_dev
> - -> playground_balance_change
> - -> Tools

where playground contains main development branch (trunk), and playground_dev, playground_balance_change and others not shown are branches.

In branches, layout goes like this:

> - -> build
> - -> lib
> - -> bin
> - -> src

I mostly wanted to work with playground and playground_dev, so i have run:

> git svn init svn::/server.address:port/RepositoryHome -T playground -b playground_dev
>
> git svn fetch

However, when i have run `git branch -r` to check how branches were imported, i found with my growing horror, that there were, besides "origin/trunk", "branches" like "origin/bin", "origin/lib", " origin/src" and so on.

How can i ensure correct mapping of branches between local working copy/git repository and the server?

Is it possible to fix the situation without fully fetching, as process takes a lot of time (roughly 16 hours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved in 2 steps.

1. First, delete all errroneously-tracked branches.
2. Add correct branches to repository.

To delete offending remote references, one can find them with `git branch -r`, and then remove with `git branch -D`.

I haven't found "proper" command-line based solution for second step, but fortunately git-svn documentation, more specifically [Configuration section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_configuration) gives enough details to do things by hand.

Most important thing is, one cannot just set a single branch to track svn remote; in configuration only "branches" key is recognized, which necessitates usage of wildcard substitution.

So, one can just add another svn remote - by hand, in `.git/config`, copying one that is already present, changing remote name and value of "fetch" key. That way one can setup a branch that corresponds to a single remote svn branch and work as usual after.

Answer (score 0):

For `git svn` option `-b` doesn't mean "this is a branch", it means "this is a directory where all subdirectories are branches" so `git svn init -b playground_dev` takes subdirectories of `playground_dev` as branches.

I don't see any simple way to overcome that. I'd recommend to clone two times into separate repositories and combine these repos. Something like:

```
git svn clone svn::/server.address:port/RepositoryHome -T playground playground
git svn clone svn::/server.address:port/RepositoryHome -T playground_dev playground_dev

cd playground
git fetch ../playground_dev trunk:playground_dev
cd ..
rm -rf playground_dev
```

The last command fetches branch "trunk" from directory `playground_dev` to a new branch "playground_dev" in the current dir.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to fix repo by deleting erroneous references? that would at least save on a single checkout